# Unpickling a Python class

Tags: python, class, pickle

I have a problem trying to unpickle subclasses of this class. When I unpickle it, the stuff isn't there. What gives?
    class Account:

```
    def __init__(self, server, port, smtp_server, smtp_port):
        self.server = server
        self.port = port
        self.smtp_server = smtp_server
        self.smtp_port = smtp_port

        self.save()

    def save(self):
        #save account for later loading
        self.name = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(title = "Save as..")
        pickle.dump(self, open(self.name, "wr"))
```

Comment: Oh, yeah, the unpickling part is in the same module that this is in, and is called from another module. Yeah, I know it's bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your class inherit `object`?

Either way, you can specify what you want to pickle by overwriting `__getstate__`. Otherwise it should normally copy `__dict__` if you're inheriting `object`.

Comment: Ok. I thought it was a given. I'll try that, thanks. Usually, python knows what I like...

Comment: No, it didn't work. It still says that it's a nonetype, and doesen't have attributes...

Comment: So... is it working now? And if not, what class are you inheriting?

Answer (score 0):

So, Here's how I just figured it out- i moved the ugly pickle stuff (see comment) to the unpickling class, imported the classes I was pickling, and it seems like it works.

Comment: nice that you worked it out, but if you had posted the solution here, other people could have benefit from it.

Comment: I'm actually not sure where that stuff is now, since I stopped using _pickle_ in favor of other forms of serialization.